# convert BLOB to text in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, blob

I have a field in my database table with data type as `BLOB`.How can I view the content as `text/string` using a `SELECT` query in `SQL`. the content's `MIMETYPE` is `'text/xml charset=UTF8'`

I tried with this, I'm not sure if im right with the syntax

```
SELECT 
CAST((SELECT column FROM myTable WHERE ID='56')AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

and also

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CAST((SELECT column FROM myTable WHERE ID='56') 
as binary)) from BIZDOCCONTENT
```

many Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(object USING utf8)
FROM tablename
```

Comment: what do I give in place of object?

Comment: Should just be the column containing your blog. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query -

```
SELECT CONVERT(column USING utf8) FROM myTable WHERE ID=56
```

Comment: I tried this but, I get an error saying right parenthesis missing. The syntax is proper. What mite be the error?

Comment: Yes, syntax is correct, query query should work. Try to run this command in another MySQL client, e.g. in command-line client.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - I just changed the field type in phpmyadmin!  And what i see :

ALTER TABLE `pages` CHANGE `content` `content` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL
('content' - my field which was in BLOB-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HASTANE.getXXXXX(p_rowid in rowid) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    l_data long;
BEGIN
    SELECT XXXXXX INTO l_data FROM XXXXX WHERE rowid = p_rowid;
    RETURN substr(l_data, 1, 4000);
END getXXXXXX;
```

Answer (score -2):

Set your content type in php:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg"); //Send the content Type here.
print $data['blob_data'];
```

Comment: I am not using PHP! Is there anything I can do about this in java/ sql. Please help!