# IMAGE datatype - Migrate MsSql to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm migrating a database from MsSql 2008 to MySql.
I have a table in MsSql which stores a string in an image field.
This is how it is retrieved in MsSql.

**Sql :**

```
SELECT UserId, Template2, CAST(CAST(Template2 AS VARBINARY)  AS VARCHAR(MAX))Template2String 
FROM AC_Users 
WHERE UserId = 11 

UserId      Template2           Template2String 
----------- ------------------- ----------------
11          0x4238384543364441  B88EC6DA
```

I need to achieve the same thing in MySql.
I googled and tried various queries, but no avail.

**MySql :**

```
SELECT  UserId, Template2, CONVERT(Template2 USING utf8) as Template2String,CAST(CAST(Template2 AS BINARY(255)) AS CHAR(10000)) Template2String_2
FROM    AC_Users
WHERE   UserId = 11

UserId  Template2   Template2String      Template2String_2
------  ---------   ---------------      -----------------
11      ...         0x4238384543364441   0x4238384543364441
```

Referenced : [convert BLOB to text in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869572/convert-blob-to-text-in-sql)

Comment: What's the binary value of the blob field in MySQL? To me it seems that you stored the textual representation of `0x4238384543364441` into the blob, therefore when you convert its value to string, you actually get back `0x4238384543364441` again. Moreover, that binary data does not seem to be utf8, that seems to be plain ASCII.

Comment: You are casting to varbinary but you didn't specify a length. This means it will default to a specific length. Do you know that default? I know I can't remember it without looking it up. You should specify it as varbinary(max) when dealing with images.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for your help.You are right it is stored as a text in BLOB field

Comment: In MySQL you do not necessarily have to explicitly cast the binary contents of a blob to string because MySQL does it implicitly if the binary value is used in a string context. The only reason to use explicit casting is to make sure that the right character set is used for the conversion.